# Qt C++ return string value

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have the following code:

filter.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

class FilterModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FilterModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getText (QString text);
};
```

filter.cpp

```
#include "filter.h"
#include <QDebug>    

FilterModel::FilterModel(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent) {}

QString FilterModel::getText(QString text)
{
    QString qmltext = text;
    qmltext != NULL ? qDebug() << qmltext
                    : qDebug() << "TEXT = NULL";

    return qmltext;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "abonentstable.h"
#include "filter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    AbonentsSqlModel *abonentsSqlModel = new AbonentsSqlModel;
    abonentsSqlModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM abonents");

    FilterModel *filterModel = new FilterModel;
    filterModel->setSourceModel(abonentsSqlModel);

    filterModel->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
    filterModel->setFilterWildcard("9");

    QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("abonents", filterModel);
    context->setContextProperty("filter", filterModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

And the .qml file part:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
...
    onTextChanged: {
        filter.getText(textField.text)
    }
...
}
```

Method `getText()` gets text (suddenly!) from QML `TextField` and prints it into debugger, it works fine. But as you can see, I have code for table sorting.
The following problem is: now sorting mask is "9", it works, but I need to return `QString qmltext` from `getText()` in some way and put it into `filterModel->setFilterWildcard()` in `main.cpp` like that:

```
QString qmlText = filterModel.getText(QString);
...
filterModel->setFilterWildcard(qmlText);
```

Of course, it's just an example, it doesn't works and I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand what you want to do, but I think you need something like that (if you really need the return value):

```
QString FilterModel::getText(const QString& text)
{
setFilterWildcard(text);
return text;
}
```

By the way:

```
 qmltext != NULL
```

is not working. Use instead:

```
qmltext.isEmpty() == false
```